# github and a private readonly repository

Tags: github

I don't see any recent answers on how to do this.  Basically, I want to give just certain users access to readonly of my repository so they can generate pull requests.

Is there an update or is the answer move the repository to bitbucket.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Organization and transfer or create the repo under the organization. Organizations can grant read-only access to their repos.